# Create a dataframe with columns and their unique values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unique

I have tried looking for a way to create a dataframe of columns and their unique values. I know this has less use cases but would be a great way to get an initial idea of unique values. It would look something like this....

| State | County | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Colorado | Denver | Denver |
| Colorado | El Paso | Colorado Springs |
| Colorado | Larimar | Fort Collins |
| Colorado | Larimar | Loveland |

Turns into this...

| State | County | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Colorado | Denver | Denver |
|  | El Paso | Colorado Springs |
|  | Larimar | Fort Collins |
|  |  | Loveland |

Comment: Does `df.set_index(['State', 'County'])` do what you want? Wouldn't save to a file that way, but if you're just trying to visualize it, that's an option.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `mask` and a lambda

```
df.mask(cond=df.apply(lambda x : x.duplicated(keep='first')), other='')

      State   County              City
0  Colorado   Denver            Denver
1            El Paso  Colorado Springs
2            Larimar      Fort Collins
3                             Loveland
```

Comment: You can directly pass the other value to `mask` (`df.mask(..., '')`), no need to use `fillna` ;)

Comment: this one is the fastest by a long shot, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @mozway didn't know that I need to go through `mask` in detail it's very powerful! changing my answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible example. Please add this next time to your future questions to help others answer your question.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': ['Colorado', 'Colorado', 'Colorado', 'Colorado'], 
    'County': ['Denver', 'El Paso', 'Larimar', 'Larimar'],
    'City': ['Denver', 'Colorado Springs', 'Fort Collins', 'Loveland']
})

df

    State     County   City
0   Colorado  Denver   Denver
1   Colorado  El Paso  Colorado Springs
2   Colorado  Larimar  Fort Collins
3   Colorado  Larimar  Loveland
```

Drop duplicates from each column separately and then concatenate. Fill `NaN` with empty string.

```
pd.concat([df[col].drop_duplicates() for col in df], axis=1).fillna('')

    State     County        City
0   Colorado  Denver        Denver
1   El Paso   Colorado      Springs
2   Larimar   Fort Collins
3             Loveland
```

Comment: I like this one. My only change would use list comprehension so it can be used for any dataframe with n columns. Something like `pd.concat([df[col_name].drop_duplicates() for col_name in df], axis=1)`

Comment: Even better. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have come up with, hope to help others looking for something like it!

```
def create_unique_df(df) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """ take a dataframe and creates a new one containing unique values for each column
    note, it only works for two columns or more

    :param df: dataframe you want see unique values for
    :param type: pandas.DataFrame
    return: dataframe of columns with unique values
    """
    # using list() allows us to combine lists down the line
    data_series = df.apply(lambda x: list( x.unique() ) )

    list_df = data_series.to_frame()

    # to create a df from lists they all neet to be the same leng. so we can append null 
    # values
    # to lists and make them the same length. First find differenc in length of longest list and
    # the rest
    list_df['needed_nulls'] = list_df[0].str.len().max() - list_df[0].str.len()

    # Second create a column of lists with one None value
    list_df['null_list_placeholder'] = [[None] for _ in range(list_df.shape[0])]

    # Third multiply the null list times the difference to get a list we can add to the list of
    # unique values making all the lists the same length. Example: [None] * 3  == [None, None, 
    # None]
    list_df['null_list_needed'] = list_df.null_list_placeholder * list_df.needed_nulls
    list_df['full_list'] = list_df[0] + list_df.null_list_needed

    unique_df = pd.DataFrame(
        list_df['full_list'].to_dict()
    )

    return unique_df
```